# How to GROUP BY in where clause with ContentProvider?

Tags: java, android, sql, android-contentprovider

Helo, I've got this code, which query the instances in calendarcontract:

```
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI + "/" +
            Long.toString(from) + "/" +
            Long.toString(to));

    String[] mProjection =
            {
                    CalendarContract.Instances._ID,
                    CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_ID,
                    CalendarContract.Instances.CALENDAR_ID,
                    CalendarContract.Instances.TITLE,
                    CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_LOCATION,
                    CalendarContract.Instances.DESCRIPTION,
                    CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_COLOR,
                    CalendarContract.Instances.DTSTART,
                    CalendarContract.Instances.DTEND,
                    CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_TIMEZONE,
                    CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_END_TIMEZONE,
                    CalendarContract.Instances.DURATION,
                    CalendarContract.Instances.ALL_DAY,
                    CalendarContract.Instances.RRULE,
                    CalendarContract.Instances.RDATE,
                    CalendarContract.Instances.EXDATE

            };


    ContentResolver cr2 = this.c.getContentResolver();
    String selection2 = "( " + selection_allcalendars + " (" + CalendarContract.Instances.RRULE + " IS NOT NULL) AND (deleted != 1) AND (" + CalendarContract.Instances.ALL_DAY + " = 0))";
    Cursor cur2 = cr2.query(uri, mProjection, selection2, null, CalendarContract.Instances.DTSTART + " ASC");
```

How can I remove double instances from query? I want to use a "GROUP BY" clause, but I don't know how to do that.

Please help me :-)

Thanks!

Edit:

I want to group by EVENT_ID, because I get multiple entries. This ist the whole code I use for recurring events:

ContentResolver cr2 = this.c.getContentResolver();
        String selection2 = "( " + selection_allcalendars + " (" + CalendarContract.Instances.RRULE + " IS NOT NULL) AND (deleted != 1) AND (" + CalendarContract.Instances.ALL_DAY + " = 0))";
        Cursor cur2 = cr2.query(uri, mProjection, selection2, null, CalendarContract.Instances.DTSTART + " ASC");

```
    ArrayList<String> checkexists = new ArrayList<>();

    while (cur2.moveToNext()) {
        String eventid = cur2.getString(cur2.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_ID));

        if(checkexists.contains(eventid)) {

        }
        else {
            checkexists.add(eventid);


        String rrule = cur2.getString(cur2.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Instances.RRULE));

        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin");
        Long dtstart;
        try {
            dtstart = Long.parseLong(cur2.getString(cur2.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Instances.DTSTART)));

            dtstart = tz.getOffset(dtstart) + dtstart;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            dtstart = 0l;
        }


        Long dtend;
        try {
            dtend = dtstart + RFC2445ToMilliseconds(cur2.getString(cur2.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Instances.DURATION)));

            /* dtend = Long.parseLong(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND)));
            dtend = tz.getOffset(dtend) + dtend; */
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            dtend = 0l;
        }


        Calendar cal4 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal4.setTimeInMillis(dtstart);

        LocalDate localdate = new LocalDate(cal4.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal4.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, cal4.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        long calendar_id = Long.valueOf(cur2.getString(cur2.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Instances.CALENDAR_ID)));
        String id = cur2.getString(cur2.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Instances._ID));

        String title = cur2.getString(cur2.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Instances.TITLE));
        String eventlocation = cur2.getString(cur2.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_LOCATION));
        String description = cur2.getString(cur2.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Instances.DESCRIPTION));
        String eventcolor = cur2.getString(cur2.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_COLOR));
        String eventtimezone = cur2.getString(cur2.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_TIMEZONE));
        String eventtimezone_end = cur2.getString(cur2.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_END_TIMEZONE));
        String duration = cur2.getString(cur2.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Instances.DURATION));
        int allday = Integer.valueOf(cur2.getString(cur2.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Instances.ALL_DAY)));

        rrule = "RRULE:" + rrule;

        long lastrecurrencetime;
        if(rrule.contains("UNTIL")) {
            lastrecurrencetime = RruleHelper.getUntil(rrule).getTimeInMillis();
        }
        else {
            lastrecurrencetime = -1;
        }

        //System.out.println("EEE: " + title + " " + rrule);
        try {

            ArrayList<ReadEvent> recurrenceevents = new ArrayList<>();


            for (LocalDate date : LocalDateIteratorFactory.createLocalDateIterable(rrule, localdate, true)) {
              //  System.out.println("GGG:" + title + " " + i);

                Calendar newcal_from = Calendar.getInstance();
                newcal_from.setTimeInMillis(dtstart);
                newcal_from.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, date.getDayOfMonth());
                newcal_from.set(Calendar.MONTH, date.getMonthOfYear() - 1);
                newcal_from.set(Calendar.YEAR, date.getYear());

                long dtstart_new = newcal_from.getTimeInMillis();

                long dtend_new = dtstart_new + RFC2445ToMilliseconds(cur2.getString(cur2.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Instances.DURATION)));

                if (dtstart_new >= from && dtstart_new <= to) {
                    ReadEvent newreadevent = new ReadEvent(calendar_id, id, eventid, title, eventlocation, description, eventcolor, dtstart_new, dtend_new, eventtimezone, eventtimezone_end, duration, allday, rrule);
                    newreadevent.setFirstReccurenceTime(dtstart);
                    newreadevent.setLastReccurenceTime(lastrecurrencetime);


                    if(!checkIfAlreadyExits(readevent, newreadevent)) {
                        //newreadevent.setReccurenceCount(i);
                        readevent.add(newreadevent);
                    }
                }

                if (dtstart_new > to) {
                    break;
                }


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        }

    }
```

Comment: There is no requirement for a `ContentProvider` that you did not write to use SQLite or any other SQL-compliant database. That is why the `ContentResolver` API is not using full SQL syntax.

Comment: Hmm. I've got the problem, that querying RRULE entries like the code above leads into multiple entries. I update the whole code.